# R script loses some values of column when I use fill=TRUE option

Tags: r

I'm facing an issue with one of my R scripts. I'm using R on Ubuntu.

The script is supposed to open up a temporary file in R, delete and rearrange columns and then save it as a new temporary file. The file the script is supposed to open (tempfile2.xyz) is rather long and the data looks like this:

```
ATOM   /   1 / N /  ALA / A / 2  /  -14.451 /  3.633 / -3.578 / 1.00 / 41.50  /  N
```

I have added backslashes to indicate different columns.

I would like to take columns 12, 7, 8 and 9 and delete the rest, so it would look like this:

```
N -14.451 3.633 -3.578
```

The script is supposed to do that with:

```
x <- read.table("tempfile2.xyz", header=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
y <- x[,c(12,7,8,9)]
write.table(y, file="tempfile3.xyz")

q()
```

Some of the files work just fine, but others give me the error:

> "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines,
>   na.strings,  :   line X did not have Y elements".

I tried to counter the error with using the fill=TRUE option, but then I lose some of the data.

```
11     C -12.008  -0.738     -0.787
12     C -12.459  -2.061     -0.201
13        -2.810   0.378       0.55
14        -2.372  -0.384       0.55
15     C -10.777   0.534     -2.768
```

So some of the data from the original 12th column goes missing, and I have no idea why.

The data is originally from .pdb file from which the original data is extracted with grep and made in to a temporary file which this script is then supposed to process.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Please post a little more than one line of data, perhaps a couple that work fine and a couple that do not. Otherwise we can't reproduce the problem. (It seems like *R* is a little overkill for this task. Have you considered the file utility `cut -b70-71,27-53` by itself? `sed` might be useful as well. Both would be faster.)

Comment: `awk '{ print $12, $7, $8, $9 }' < infile > outfile` may be faster still. On second thought, forget that, doesn't handle missing data, though the [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html) has a recipe for dealing with constant-width tables like this.

Comment: Better `awk` recipe: `awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "4 7 3 6 3 3 11 8 8 6 7 5" } { print $12, $7, $8, $9 }' < infile > outfile`.

Comment: Hi! Seems that the problem was in the .pdb -files as well. Some of the rows had too many characters on columns 3 and 4, so they would actually "touch" like this:

ATOM   /   1 / N ABCALA / A / 2  /  -14.451 /  3.633 / -3.578 / 1.00 / 41.50  /  N

And R would then count it as one column instead of two. Trying to figure out a way to go around this.

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: If it's fixed-width and not delimited, why does it matter? (*R* reads fixed-width files just fine ...)